# Question concerning proof of the Cauchy Integral Formula on the Wolfram website

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I was reading through the proof of the Cauchy Integral Formula [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyIntegralFormula.html). I do not understand 
how the transition is made from equation [(8)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/equations/CauchyIntegralFormula/Inline19.gif) to equation (9). While taking the limit as $r\to 0$, doesn't the closed curve $\gamma_r$ also vanish? So, by then the closed curve $\gamma_r$ around $z_0$ is degenerate(a point), I think.

Can you please explain what is going on?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The integrate $\oint_{\gamma_r} f(z_0 + r \mathrm{e}^{i \theta}) i \mathrm{d} \theta$ really means $\int_0^{2\pi} f( z_0 + r(\theta) \mathrm{e}^{i \theta}) i \mathrm{d} \theta$, where $r(\theta)$ is bounded by $r$, i.e. $\sup_{0\le \theta < 2\pi} r(\theta) \le r$.

With this in mind, the eq. (9) will follow by continuity of $f(z)$.

Comment: I would say that it's equation (11) that follows directly. Neither (9) nor (10) make sense really, since they refer to $r$ after having taken the limit as $r \to 0$.

Comment: @Hans, I believe you are right. Once, the limit has been taken, the equations 8 and 9 do not make sense.

Comment: Yes, and my answer kind of suggests what they should be replaced with.

Comment: @Sasha, good efforts. What is the difference between $r$  and $r(\theta)$?

Comment: @Sasha, since you are an R&D at Wolfram Research, you might kindly invite editors to give their views here.

Comment: $r$ is a constant radius, and $r(\theta)$ is the function that parametrically defines the contour $\gamma_r$ in polar coordinates.